# Geting 'Entity class not found' error while mapping classes to database table by hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

**Simple pojo class**

```
package practice041116;
public class Cls {
public String name;
public int roll;
public Cls(){}
public String getName() {
return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}
public int getRoll() {
return roll;
}
public void setRoll(int roll) {
this.roll = roll;
}
}
```

**The main login file**

```
package practice041116; 
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration; 
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
public class MainClass {
public static void main(String args[]){
Configuration cnfg=new Configuration();
cnfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
SessionFactory fact=cnfg.buildSessionFactory();
Session session=fact.openSession();        
Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
Cls s=new Cls();
s.setName("Taleev");
s.setRoll(23);
session.save(s);
tx.commit();
```

}
}

**The configuration file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate        
Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-    
configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://171.8.9.1;DatabaseName:test
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">
username
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">
password
</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<mapping resource="practice041116/Cls.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Mapping file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 
3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Cls" table="cls">
<id name="id" column="id" type="integer"/>
<property name="name" column="NAME" type="string"/>
<property name="roll" column="ROLL" type="integer"/>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have the specified table in my database but while execute it gives Entity Class not found Exception, i have tried various answer available on the similar question such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234868/org-hibernate-mappingexception-entity-class-not-found-using-qualified-class-n)
and few more from other sources from the net 
[Hierarchy of the project and the jar files used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J28s4.png)
Thanks in advance and forgive me if i have done some format mistake on this question as this is the first question i am posting.
[Stack trace of Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK8A0.png)

Comment: Rather good presentation for first question :) but you should also post the whole exception stacktrace because exception summary message or exception name is often  not enough.

Comment: In addition it would also be useful if you post your Cls class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your mapping file :

```
<class name="Cls" table="cls">
```

you don't specify qualified class name but just simple class name.
You should replace by :

```
<class name="practice041116.Cls" table="cls">
```

Comment: but i am getting another error which is "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://171.8.9.1;DatabaseName:test"  why i am getting is there any mistake on my code or i am missing something

Comment: This is the exception "  Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Cannot open connection "

Comment: You are welcome. You should accept the answer and re-open a new question if actual problem is solved. When the problem is related, editing the quesiton/answers of the post is relevant but when it has no relation it makes readability of post harder for community.

Comment: Ok thanks  @davidxxx i have got my answer on this problem, what do i have to do i  should leave this topic as it is or is there any procedure to close the discussion

Comment: You are welcome. You can read this information : stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer It explains the principle of accepted answer and you should the help in general because it contains some important information. Here, to summarize, when you ask a question and you consider one of answers has addressed it, you should check this answer as accepted. Concretely to do it, the author of a question has close to each proposed answer, a kind of mark he may check to consider is as accepted. When it is checked, a green mark is displayed.

Comment: It is just under the number. Look at this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052718/what-is-the-best-way-to-launch-hsqldb-for-unit-testing-when-working-with-spring?rq=1

 Look at the first answer : you see where is the green mark .

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is an ORM framework which maps a Java Object (Entity Object) to a relational database table, as you did NOT map any Entity Class to a database table you are getting this exception.

**Option(1): Using Annotations**

You need to use `@Entity` (class level mapping) and `@Column` (element level mapping) to map the java object to a database table.

**Option(2): Using mapping xml files**

As sugested by David above and also you can look at [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html)