# No Suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver... while connecting sqlserver with hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

**Configuration file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration  
DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://171.1.8.4;databaseName:master
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">
usename
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">
password
</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">
org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
</property>
<property name="hibernate.default_schema">
dbo
</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<mapping resource="practice041116/Cls.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

[Here is the stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH7gh.png)

How to resolve it as i have went through few answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w) but its not helping Thanks in advance

The rest of the code is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40436685/geting-entity-class-not-found-error-while-mapping-classes-to-database-table-by)

Comment: which server you are using ? Tomcat or jetty or weblogic ?

Comment: i am using Apache server and  microsoft sql server 2008 R2 for database management

Comment: Did not get any solution yet..

Comment: Add SQLServer jar file to the Apache lib folder and restart the server

Comment: this error has been resolved but now i am facing a new error which says com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset is it possible to solve it from here or need to post a new question.

Comment: And i did not add SQLServer jar file to the Apache lib folder but i have sqljdbc4.jar file in my class path, and the mistake i was doing, here i was syntactically wrong as  i have defined the <hibernate.connection.url> as jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver and the rest of the detail, so i have changed it to "jdbc:sqlserver",  it solved the error